# Use Shift+F12 in an application

Tags: macos, keyboard, dashboard, shortcut

I am using an application which has a shortcut that uses `Shift + F12`. But when I do that on my mac, it goes to the dashboard. Which is very irritating. How can I quickly bypass that feature and send the shortcut to the app?

Comment: have you tried holding the fn button at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **System Preferences** → **Mission Control** and change the **Show Dashboard** shortcut to something else.

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's quite lame that you have to do that.. But thank you anyway

Comment: Shift+F12 was probably a poor choice for the app developer to have made. What app?

Comment: @samh Afaik, ⇧F12 is not default for showing the dashboard (I changed it for my screenshot) so it's not that bad

Comment: On my Mac, F12 is show dashboard which means ⇧F12 will be the slowed-animation version of show dashboard.

Comment: @samh Ah, fair enough. I presume that's on a full keyboard with no FN rather than MacBook?

Comment: Macbook Pro with Retina Display. "F12" meaning, then, Fn + Volume Up/F12 key.